# Multiple queries in one mysql (Using datatable or not)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

In my database I have 4 tables :

The principal table :

```
P(T_P, T, P, title)
```

And 2 others table link with T_P:

```
E(T_P, EE, AA, BB)
G(T_P, CC, DD, EE)
```

And one other table `D`, with a `TYPE` argument.

In my result, I would like to have 3 columns based on the 3 type.

To display, I use datatable with server side processing, because the `P` table has 500.000 rows.

Actually, without datatable I use **4** different queries:

- One for getting table P, table D and table E arguments.
- One for getting table D with type A
- One for getting table D with type B and
- One for getting table D with type C.

These work great, but I need to use datatable.

I don't know if I'm clear enough, so I've drawn a little schema.

[image: All examples]

Comment: You could improve your question a great deal by providing the statements to create the schema you have drawn. Most users aren't going to recreate your schema themselves, so providing this will allow users to answer your question with a fully tested example.

Comment: It would also be helpful for you to provide sample data and the desired result of the query from that sample data.  Maybe provide the queries that you're currently using as well.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Please give create table query for makejob easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you close to what you need.  Can I ask why you're not using verbose names for tables/columns?  You're just making your own life, and the life of whoever takes over this project next, much much harder.

```
SELECT tP.T_P,
       tP.T,
       tP.P,
       tP.Title,
       tE.EE,
       tG.CC,
       tDa.X AS A,
       tDb.X AS B,
       tDc.X AS C
FROM P AS tP
LEFT JOIN E AS tE ON tP.T_P = tE.T_P
LEFT JOIN G AS tG ON tP.T_P = tG.T_P
LEFT JOIN D AS tDa ON tP.T = tDa.T AND tP.P = tDa.P AND tDa.Type = 'A'
LEFT JOIN D AS tDb ON tP.T = tDb.T AND tP.P = tDb.P AND tDb.Type = 'B'
LEFT JOIN D AS tDc ON tP.T = tDc.T AND tP.P = tDc.P AND tDc.Type = 'C'
```

[image]

Comment: This answer doesnt provide the desire output. Here you are putting every X in a different row instead of the same row as is show in the last picture

Comment: Edited the answer, try now, had `tDa.A` `tDb.B` and `tDc.C` instead of `tDa.X` `tDb.X` and `tDc.X`

Comment: nope that doesnt work like that. you are doing cartasian product between P and D so you have a row for each D. That is why my answer has `GROUP BY`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It is not a cartesian join, look again. you would get multiple rows only if table D had multiple rows with the same values for T, P, and Type.

Comment: no worries, it's not easy to check this stuff when the OP only gives a screenshot to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.T_P,
       P.T,
       P.P,
       P.Title,
       E.EE,
       G.CC,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.Type = 'A' THEN X END) as A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.Type = 'B' THEN X END) as B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN D.Type = 'C' THEN X END) as C
FROM P 
LEFT JOIN E ON P.T_P = E.T_P
LEFT JOIN G ON P.T_P = G.T_P
LEFT JOIN D ON P.T = D.T 
         AND P.P = D.P 
GROUP BY 
       P.T_P,
       P.T,
       P.P,
       P.Title,
       E.EE,
       G.CC
```

Comment: You didn't specify the table for your last join.